# Passing parameters dynamically into Method.Invoke

Tags: java, reflection

I have methods in a class

```
public class ReflectionClass {
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
    public int add(int a, int b, int c) {
        return a + b + c;
    }
    public String concatenate (String a, String b, String c){
        return a + b + c;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to call these methods through reflection. All I have in hand are - the method name and the parameters. Is there a way to pass the parameters into the Method.Invoke() method dynamically based on the number/type of parameters I have in hand?

Comment: Check the types of the arguments, match them against the types of the parameters. You might be able to do something more dynamic with `MethodHandle`s.

Comment: Or make your add method expect a varargs.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard, Unfortunately, I won't be able to modify the methods I need to call. My real world methods are from another service coming in from another component.

Comment: What have you tried, and which part of the reflection documentation caused you trouble? Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), paying attention to #3: *Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the **work you've done so far** to solve the problem, and a description of the **difficulty you are having** solving it.*

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-) `public Object invoke(Object obj, Object... args)` takes a varargs argument - so you can simply pass an array of arguments there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance, get the methods, get the parameters, check the parameters by checking the type and how many... then call invoke depending of what

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class<?> cls = Class.forName("com.ReflectionClass");
    Object obj = cls.newInstance();
    for (Method m : cls.getDeclaredMethods()) {
        if (m.getParameterCount() == 3 && Arrays.asList(m.getParameterTypes()).contains(String.class)) {
            String a = "A";
            String b = "B";
            String c = "C";
            Object returnVal = m.invoke(obj, a, b, c);
            System.out.println((String) returnVal);
        } else if (m.getParameterCount() == 2 && Arrays.asList(m.getParameterTypes()).contains(int.class)) {
            int a = 5;
            int b = 3;
            Object returnVal = m.invoke(obj, a, b);
            System.out.println(returnVal);
    } else if (m.getParameterCount() == 3 && Arrays.asList(m.getParameterTypes()).contains(int.class)) {
            int a = 5;
            int b = 3;
            int c = 3;
            Object returnVal = m.invoke(obj, a, b, c);
            System.out.println(returnVal);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this already. It seems to appear redundant as the same code is repeating for each condition. I was looking for something more simple, a one-liner, like - m.invoke(obj, paramList) - Is there a way to pass these parameters in a list, and get the target method to take it as individual parameters? (it might seem weird, but just thinking out loud!)

Comment: yes. I have the name, number and type of parameters along with the method name. but still, the real world methods may have multiple types of parameter (parameters can have 2 strings and 1 int), so that won't work with the code you wrote.